# Writing a message without a SysOut?

Tags: java

In the program below how is it possible to write a message without a sysout. I am 
referring to    ("You must set the property messageProvider of class:"   ...)
Is there something wrong with code or did miss something in core Java

```
 public class StandardOutMessageRenderer implements MessageRenderer
    {
        private MessageProvider messageProvider;

        @Override
        public void render() {
            if (messageProvider == null) {            
                throw new RuntimeException( "You must set the property messageProvider of class:" + 
                        StandardOutMessageRenderer.class.getName());
            }

            System.out.println(messageProvider.getMessage());
        }

        @Override    
        public void setMessageProvider(MessageProvider provider) {
            this.messageProvider = provider;
        }

        @Override
        public MessageProvider getMessageProvider() {
            return this.messageProvider;
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to *change* the code to print the message instead of throwing an exception? Or are you asking how the throw ends up printing to the console window even though it is not using SysOut? Or what exactly *are* you asking?

Comment: Please format your code for human readability. Correct indentation helps clarity.

Comment: Andreas,  I am referring to ("You must set the property messageProvider of class:" ...). That part of the code. I took it from pro spring 4 book. without a sysout how is it possible to simmply write (" you must...

Comment: Still don't know what you are asking. The very next statement has a `println`, so if you *want* to print, just write another print statement. The line you reference currently throws an exception with the given text, it doesn't print anything, though the text may get printed by the code *handling* the exception. If you don't understand exceptions, that's an entirely different question, and you should read more about them, and what they are good for.

Comment: @Andreas  What part of exception handling did I miss? Please tell me, i will go back and refer

Comment: The part where a `throw` statement doesn't print anything, which it seems you think it does. The `throw` statement starts exception processing, rolling back method calls until a `catch` statement catches the exception. The code in the `catch` block may then do whatever it wants with the exception, including printing it, but that is the choice of the `catch` code. The `throw` itself doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're refering to exception.
Exceptions have try-catch mechanism. If they're catched in code - they're worked with in code.

But! if they're not catched, they are thrown higher. You should refer to Exception chapter in your book :)
After it's catched by mainstream the program crashes. But before that it prints message inside exception to you default output. I.e. default output stream.
And guess what's default output stream by default in Java? system.err.println(exception.printStackTrace()). Which is analogue to system.out.println...

That's not very deep and insightful, but to really understand how it works you first need to understand daemon, streams, exceptions, and default JVM behaviour.

ps: it may be too early to read book on spring if you don't know how exceptions work

Comment: Oh,so this is related to Exceptions. Can you give more clarity, as to what part of exception handling helps in printing out messages like that? I know exception handling but even there to print messages, I thought we use a Sysout.

Comment: Perhaps you should familiarize yourself with the basic concepts of Java before trying to learn about spring...

Comment: I can't. At least not here. Explaining how exception handling works for non-catched Exceptions is a big chapter in a book which cannot be reproduced to comment section. Please google :)

Comment: @ChristianFrommeyer  I know exceptions. Even there we use SysOut to print messages, right?

Comment: Nope, we used saved reference to output stream in which we pass stackTrace of exception. Seriously, read a chapter on exceptions and Oracle's documentation, the topic's too wast for comment section.

Comment: Well yes and no. Usually exceptions are printed (if at all) to System.err not .out. But if there is no console to print to they usually go to a file or socket or... not to System.out.

Comment: Oops, true, forgot that it's not system.out. corrected my answer.

Comment: @PoWong Try writing a Hello Exception (spoof on Hello World) program to see/learn what happens: `public static void main(String[] args) { throw new RuntimeException("Hello Exception"); }`. The `throw` statement doesn't print anything, but the Java runtime will print any uncaught exceptions to the console. If the program doesn't have a console, then nothing is printed anywhere.

Comment: @Andreas Now thats a start, I will try the example you gave me..brb

Comment: @Andreas this is what the console says in red color    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Hello Exception
 at Runtime1.main(Runtime1.java:6)

Comment: @PoWong So now you know how the Java runtime prints any uncaught exception. Hopefully you also learned that the `throw` statement itself doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use a logging framework of your choice. Java.util.logging comes with the jre . Log4j and logback are quite popular. Slf4j provides additional abstraction...

Comment: This not a Frame work related query. Is there an explanation to to the line I am referring to. I took that example from a Book and I hit a dead end at that line.

Comment: There is no message printed at that line.